# How to extract image and sound files from a MDB file

Tags: ms-access

I have a MDB file, which include many images and wave files. I need to extract them.

I tried to open the MDB file with access 2007. I can see several tables, 4 or 5. And I can see the records in them. I also tried to open it with a tools on Mac book. I can see about 20 tables. I can also check the records.

But, how can I get the files? From the record, I can see many fields' value like "pic\m1.jpg", "s1\sound\a1.wav".

I can make sure the file exists in this DB file. But I just do't know how to extract them.

Comment: If the field type is text, then the file is not stored in MS Access. An mdb with a lot of embedded files would  be huge. Check the file location at `..pic\` for `m1.jpg`

Comment: It's a relative path. Probably relative to the location the Access file was opened from or some hardcoded parent folder somewhere else.

Comment: yes, the MDB file is really huge, about 2.1G. There is only one MDB file and a exe file. When I open the software, I can see the picture and check the sound. So I can make sure all the files are saved in MDB file.